# I'm having problems with my first servlet

Tags: java, servlets

This is the code to my servlet...

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {
    private String message;

    public void init(){
        message="Hello World";
    }
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<h1>"+message+"</h1>");
    }

    public void destroy(){
    }
}
```

I'm using xampp's tomcat 7

and this is my web.xml file

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0"
 metadata-complete="true">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>HelloWorld</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/HelloWorld</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

My web.xml is in %TOMCAT_HOME%/webapps/ROOT/WEB_INF directory
and my HelloWorld.class is in %TOMCAT_HOME%/webapps/ROOT/WEB_INF/classes directory.

when I try to run my file from my browser I type

`http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld`

in the addressbar
and the following Servlet exception shows up

```
type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class HelloWorld
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:269)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorld (wrong name: com/HelloWorld/HelloWorld)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:752)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2820)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1150)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:269)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.21 logs.
```

Please suggest a method to run my app properly...

Comment: it seems like you forgot to add the ServletException

Comment: Which SErvletException?

Comment: It was a large page with a lot of errors somehow I wasn't able to post it here.Stack Overflow would keep giving error of indentation even though I took care of it.

Comment: do one thing while posting code, paste it in the text area then select all code and press `ctrl + k`

Comment: here you go this is the servlet exception

Comment: does your class have a package or have you put it in a directory called com/HelloWorld/

Comment: looks like your class is defined inside a package called `com/HelloWorld`, is there a package definition at beginning of the java file

Comment: "I'm having problems with my first servlet" needs to be in the form a question to follow the formidable Q&A format.

Answer (score 6):

**Don't use the default (empty) package; give it a name instead**...

```
package com.xyz;
...
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet
```

**Update web.xml to reflect new package...**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.xyz.HelloWorld</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

**Make sure the servlet class file resides in...**

```
WEB-INF/classes/com/xyz/HelloWorld.class
```

Comment: It still does not work,what should I type in my browser's address bar

Comment: What error are you getting now? Unless you set a context-path, `http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld` should still work.

Comment: Looking at the original error, I'm wondering where is `com/HelloWorld/HelloWorld` coming from; do you have HelloWorld defined in a JAR file on the classpath, but forgot about it? If TC still complains with the same error, change the above package name to `com.HelloWorld` (and servlet mapping), then test again.

Comment: I have redefined package to com.test.HelloWorld

Comment: why have blank pages started appearing...now even errors are disappeared

Comment: I got it working on TC7, same code, I used `@WebServlet("/HelloWorld")' instead of web.xml, like @Prasad mentioned, deployed to TC folder `/webapps/webso/WEB-INF`, don't use `ROOT`, try again.

Comment: I'm using Java 1.6 and Tomcat 7 on Eclipse STS, you need `import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;` for the annotation.

Answer (score 0):

follow the following steps

- Under the webapps folder, create a new folder for your webapp.
  HelloWorld
- Under HelloWorld create another folder called WEB-INF.
- Under WEB-INF, create a folder called classes.
- under WEB-INF, put your web.xml .
- under the classes folder create your package structure com/HelloWorld
- put your class file under classes/com/HelloWorld folder
- restart the tomcat

Answer (score 0):

Default packages are discouraged, always put your servlets and classes in some package. Lets say you have package `com.practice` and `HelloWorld` servlet in it then your `web.xml` becomes

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.practice.HelloWorld</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

If you are defining servlet in `com.practice` package i.e. path should be `WEB-INF/classes/com/practice/HelloWorld`

Also, if you are using tomcat 7, then you do not have to use servlet mapping in web.xml at all.
You can simply use annotations for the same.
e.g.

```
@WebServlet("/HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {
    private String message;

    public void init() {
        message = "Hello World";
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<h1>" + message + "</h1>");
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Here `WebServlet` is the annotation that is equalivalent to defining servlet in `web.xml` and `"/HelloWorld"` is the url pattern

Comment: the program wouldn't compile when I type @WebServlet("/HelloWorld")

Comment: You said you are using tomcat 7, right? tomcat 7 supports servlet 3.0 specification. Check what servlet version you are using by `right click` on project select `properties` then click `project facets`. There you can see servlet version

Comment: I'm using notepad to write programs not any IDE where I can right click the project.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why you are just typing the servlet mapping url to invoke your web application as follows.
[http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld](http://www.localhost.com:8080/HelloWorld)

it should be in the following format

[http://localhost:8080/your-web-application-name/url-pattern](http://www.localhost.com:8080/your-web-application-name/url-pattern)

for example, assume that you are invoking HelloWorld url mapping on Web Application called MyWebApp . it should be called as below.

host:port/MyWebApp/HelloWorld

Answer (score -1):

I also faced the same issue. I resolved the issue as follows.
IDE Eclipse Photon

Go to this path:
Build Path> Configure Build Path > Source

Change the path of "Default output folder":
[project name]/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes

[image: project name[]/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes]

Try with this, Sometime it won't work.
If it is not working, create a new Java program with `Public static void main(String[] args)` and Run that project as Java Application, so your project will update and a new .class file will be created:
[image: new .class file will be created]